# How to show data in blade by id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have to make a website for student hostels in my country I have a special page for every hostel that shows its all photos and property but I don't know how can I do this with the hostel id when I have a hostel table if someone can help me, please! 
thank's for all

This is my hostel **controller** code:

```
class HostelDetailsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request,$detail_id)
    {

        // $id = $request->query($detail_id);
        $file_details = HostelDetails::all();

        $files = Attachment::get();
        return view('khabgah_details', compact(['file_details', 'files']));

    }
}
```

This is my hostel page **blade** code:

```
@foreach($file_details as $file)
    <div class="card-title text-center">
        <div class="mt-4"></div>
        <i class="fa fa-home mt-4 text-center" style="font-size:45px;"></i>
        <h5 class="mt-3 text-center"> لیلیه نرگس  </h5>
        <h6 class="fa fa-phone"> شماره تماس: {{ $file->phone_number }} </h6>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

It doesn't show any error message but when I load the page it shows all my records in the table

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking for. you want to show a single hostel details?

Comment: $file_details = HostelDetails::where('id',$detail_id')->first();

Answer (score 1):

```
//You can get the id from the index page of the hostel
public function show($id)
{
    $details = Detail::where('hostel_id', '=', $id)->get();
    return view('HostelDetailPage',compact('details'));
}
```